# Wired Gigabit ethernet connection speed reset to 10 or 100 Mb/s on reboot of Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: performance, settings, ethernet, reboot

I have an ethernet card in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system that supports 1000baseT/Full. Virtually every time I reboot the system due to a system upgrade, the card is reset to 10 or 100 Mb/s, and I have to use ethtool to reset it to 1000 Mb/s. Which system file do I need to edit to set the speed to 1000 Mb/s when the system is started?

Comment: I found the answer to my question. Edit the /etc/network/interfaces file (you'll need to use sudo to launch your editor of choice in order to save your changes) to add the following line at the beginning of the file:

Comment: I found the answer to my question. Edit the /etc/network/interfaces file (you'll need to use sudo to launch your editor of choice in order to save your changes) to add the following line at the beginning of the file:

pre-up /sbin/ethtool -s [name of your interface] autoneg off speed 1000 duplex full

If ethtool is not installed, first use:

sudo apt-get install ethtool net-tools

The name of your interface can be displayed using ifconfig.

If you're not sure of the settings your card supports, use:

sudo ethtool [name of your interface]